# Spring: two ways of detecting the browser locale

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am aware of two ways:

```
RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request);
LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
```

Do they always deliver the same result?

Regards and thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/RequestContextUtils.html#getLocale-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-) of `RequestContextUtils`:

> Retrieve the current locale from the given request, using the
>   LocaleResolver bound to the request by the DispatcherServlet (if
>   available), falling back to the request's accept-header Locale.
>
> This method serves as a straightforward alternative to the standard
>   Servlet ServletRequest.getLocale() method, falling back to the latter
>   if no more specific locale has been found.
>
> Consider using LocaleContextHolder.getLocale() which will normally be populated with the same Locale.

It seems that it will normally be populated with the same value, but not always

Comment: geoand, though it is not the definitive answer, but good to know!